# How to use two singin and singup methods of firebase in single android project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a college application where i have put two section one for students and second for faculty.
Student and Faculty both are using authentication email and password method.
Problem is that when i login from student section and do minimize the application and then clear the task and reopen the app so app is starting from the beginning and if i am taping  on faculty section so i am login there already even though i did not login  by this section.

How to tackle this Problem?

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                   FirebaseUser  authentic_user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                   if(authentic_user.isEmailVerified()) {
                       String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                       database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);
                       database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                               try {
                                   email_check = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                               } catch (NullPointerException error) {
                                   email_check = null;
                               }

                               if (email_check != null) {
                                   email.setText(email_check);
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentDashboard.class);
                                   startActivity(intent);
                                   student_login_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                               } else {
                                   student_login_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                   finish();
                               }
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                           }
                       });
                   }else
                   {
                       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Student_Email_Verification.class));
                       student_login_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }


                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Student.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    student_login_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really simply before going to faculty Section check if you are logged in already.

if yes then try

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

This will help you out to log out from existing account and login again with another faculty account.

Comment: This Problem is not just faculty it is vice-versa what i am doing now i checked this condition onStart() call back method and singout if user is already login but when user again login and go to dashboard then if user press the back button user will logout because every on backpress start method call.